# Kotlin file to kotlin class

Tags: java, android, class, android-studio, kotlin

I created a kotlin file instead kotlin class, but my file is a class truly and the icon continue as follow

[image]

I would like if the icon was as follows (just why I feel comfortable so)

[image]

Thanks for any suggestions on how to solve it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a class in that file with the same name of the file:

If the file is `MyClass.kt`

add to the file

```
class MyClass{

}
```

If the file only contains the class it will have the second icon. If you add anything else to that file it will change back to the first icon.

Answer (score 1):

The second icon (that you feel comfortable with) is for files that defines just one class with the same name as the file (a class file). If you add more stuff, then it's not a "class" file, but one containing a variety of stuff (just a file).